# System.out.println(new Date().hashCode()); will the hashcode value be different every time

Tags: java

When can the hashcode of two `new Date()` objects be the same?

For example,`new Date()` never has the same value, so will the hashcode value be different every time this code is run?

```
System.out.println(new Date().hashCode());
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: [Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#hashCode--), which describes how it is calculated.

Answer (score 4):

Date's `hashCode` uses `getTime` which returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT, calling it several times on fast modern machines is very likely to produce the same value.

When I run it on my machine, it produces the following:

```
 System.out.println(new Date().hashCode()); //1328556618
 System.out.println(new Date().hashCode()); //1328556618
 System.out.println(new Date().hashCode()); //1328556618
```

And btw, calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` several times is very likely to produce same values.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally expect two unequal objects to have different hashcodes. But according to the [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), there is never any *guarantee* that hashcodes for two objects will be different:

> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the [`equals(java.lang.Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.

But your statement that every new `Date` object has a different value is not correct. `Date` only has millisecond precision, which means that you can generate many objects in a row with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#hashCode--), the `hashCode` is calculated as:

```
(int)(this.getTime()^(this.getTime() >>> 32))
```

Therefore, two dates' hash codes create two dates with the same time:

```
Date d1 = new Date();
System.out.println(d1.hashCode());
Date d2 = new Date(d1.getTime());
System.out.println(d2.hashCode());  // Same as d1.hashCode();
```

Or set the times to be the same:

```
Date d1 = new Date();
System.out.println(d1.hashCode());
Thread.sleep(1000);  // Just to make sure they're not the same time initially.
Date d2 = new Date();
System.out.println(d2.hashCode());  // Different to d1.hashCode();
d2.setTime(d1.getTime());
System.out.println(d2.hashCode());  // Same as d1.hashCode();
```